# GetType Equal's Method return false for two same class - c#

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class like : `StoreDetail` , it inheritance from `BaseEntity` , I add a method in `BaseEntity` to copy a class to another like belowe :

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
    {
 public void Copy(BaseEntity source, BaseEntity destination)
        {
            var destinationId = destination.Id;
            var sourceType = source.GetType();
            var destinationType = destination.GetType();
            if (sourceType.Equals(destinationType))
            {
                foreach (var field in sourceType.GetFields())
                {
                    var dstinationField = destinationType.GetField(field.Name);
                    if (dstinationField == null)
                        continue;
                    dstinationField.SetValue(destination, field.GetValue(source));
                }

                foreach (var field in sourceType.GetProperties())
                {
                    var dstinationField = destinationType.GetProperty(field.Name);
                    if (dstinationField == null)
                        continue;

                    dstinationField.SetValue(destination, field.GetValue(source, null), null);
                }
            }
            destination.Id = destinationId;
        }
  }
```

first I check type of two object with this line :

```
 var sourceType = source.GetType();
        var destinationType = destination.GetType();
        if (sourceType.Equals(destinationType)){}
```

but it returns False .
I use like this :

```
StoreEntity.StoreDetail storeDetailModel = new StoreEntity.StoreDetail();
   storeDetail.Copy(storeDetail, storeDetailModel); //storeDetailselect from db
```

`storeDetail` is :

```
var storeDetail = _storeDetails.Where(row => row.StoreId == transferViewModel.SourceStoreId).FirstOrDefault();
```

`private IDbSet<StoreEntity.StoreDetail> _storeDetails;`

Comment: Can you show us what `storeDetail` looks like? What type is it?

Comment: If you debug, what is the two types?

Comment: What is `sourceType.FullName` and `destinationType.FullName`? What does equals say if you pass the same instance as source and destination?

Comment: @Verarind `sourceType` is :`System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.StoreDetail_83E7CA59AED1C4EF399FE486F5F4035A5D3A2E18D1CF8CC8B86E81299EE15240` and `destinationType.FullName ` is : `Store.DomainClasses.Entities.StoreDetail`

Comment: There is the problem. There are proxy classes. I think @CaringDev gave you the correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually EntityFramework creates so-called proxy classes. The entity loaded from DB will thus have a type similar to `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxy.StoreEntity.StoreDetail_SomeNumbersHere`.
The proxy will however be derived from your base-class, so you could

- check whether the entity from the DB is assignable to your class
- turn proxy generation off, if you do not use lazy loading (see [Working with Proxies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592886.aspx))
- use a pre-built tool for copying (e.g. [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/))
- turn [change tracking off](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679169(v=vs.103).aspx), if you are copying just because you don't want changes to be eventually persisted (usually model and DTO classes are not the same)
- use a simpler ORM (e.g. [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net))